# Is there a button component with a transparent background or can you create one?

Tags: java, android, components, custom-component

I'm looking for a button just like this (transparent background and when clicked it becomes gray):[Image of the component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBw3T.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm just looking for a button like in the picture.


```

<Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@android: color/transparent"
                android: gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="על סמך הפעילות האחרונה שלך"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not so clear, but here is [how you can create custom or style Button](https://www.google.com/amp/s/mobikul.com/styling-and-theming-in-android/amp/)

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded.
The solution is:

xml(button_category_template):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="20sp"
 />
```

java(MainActivity):

```
public class startActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    Button btn = (Button)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.button_category_template, null);
    lnr = findViewById(R.id.layoutApp);
        lnr.addView(btn);
   }
}
```

It may be possible to do it in a simpler way, but in my project I used it this way.